# Change outgoing repo on a hgsubversion checkout

Tags: svn, mercurial, repository, checkout

For various convoluted reasons, I had to svnsync a subversion repo to be local, before I could clone it with hgsubversion, rather than cloning it straight from the 'source'.

Now that has worked successfully, (20secs vs 3hours then fail) I wish to change the pull URI back to the original source, since it works fine under normal circumstances. However, if i change the .hg/hgrc URI back to the original source and do a hg pull to check it's worked, I get a  `abort: unable to operate on unrelated repository` message. Obviously, the 2 svn repos are identical, but even the `--force` flag doesn't seem to convince hg(subversion) that they are identical.

I also tried running a `hg convert` on the local svn repo, however when i went to pull from the original source, it seems that it hadn't retained the history (despite it being there already) and decided to pull everything again.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I seem to have got the original checkout to work, by pulling in steps of 100(ish)

However, since the question still has not been answered, i won't add this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a note in the [hgsubversion docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) that there is a memory leak on long pulls that requires repeated pulls.